# Get row which has max version value but isn't active

Tags: mysql, pdo, max, self-join

I do have a table where changes are always inserted. For this purposes, a version number is increased on each insert but one version is always set manually to be the active one. I would now like to retrieve all rows where the row with the highest version does not have 'active'=true.

```
| UID | Version | Active | Name  |
----------------------------------
| 001 |       1 | _      | Peter |
| 001 |       2 | X      | Paul  |
| 001 |       3 | _      | Petra |
| 002 |       1 | _      | Walt  |
| 002 |       2 | X      | Jan   |
| 003 |       1 | X      | Brad  |
```

The result of the query should only return uid 001 as there is a max version of 3 which is not active.

I assume that I need some kind of self-join?

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: You don't need a self-join. Get the row with the highest version, then filter it with `HAVING active != 'X'` to remove the active ones.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1 for how to get the row with the max version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use subquery  and inner join

```
select uid, version
from my_table m
inner join  (
  select  uid, max(version) max_version
  from my_table 
  group by uid
) t ON t.uid = m.uid and t.max_version = m.version 
where active ='-'
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted!